# How to move the fitting curve over the scattering plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, z-order

I have scattering data coveres a fitting curve. The fitting curve is red while the data is blue. Here is my code. I am trying to use zorder, but not work. How to bring the fitting curve to front?

```
ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax1.set_xlabel('Time[s]')
ax1.set_ylabel('Current[uA]')
ax2.set_ylabel('QE[%]')
ax1.set_ylim([ydown,yup])
ax2.set_ylim([(ydown/laser90)*2.32*100,(yup/laser90)*phe*100])
ax1.plot(cathode90[:,0],cathode90[:,1]*10**6,'b.',label='Exp. Data',zorder=0)
ax2.plot(cathode90[:,0],(cathode90[:,1]*10**6/laser90)*phe*100,'b.')
ax1.plot(x90,yfit90,'r-',label="Fitting",zorder=-1)
ax1.text(cathode90[-1,0]/3,0.5,'Decay time =%.1f s' % t90)
ax1.legend(loc='right')
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `zorder=1` instead of `zorder=-1` in `ax1.plot(x90,yfit90,'r-',label="Fitting",zorder=-1)`? http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/zorder_demo.html

Comment: As @eclark said, set `zorder=1`, since it's always assumed that we're viewing from the top. But if you omit the `zorder` parameters, you'll get each new plot on top of the old ones: just what you need.